# Omitting the flex-grow value in flex shorthand

Tags: css, flexbox, specifications, flex-grow

In this resource: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex it says that, when using the `flex` shorthand, if you omit `flex-grow`, it is set to 1. But how can you omit it in the first place?

Comment: You first have to add `display:flex` to its parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same [`flex` property definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex) your referenced, it also says this:

```
Value: none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

The double bar (`||`) separates two or more options, and one or more must be specified ([source](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#comb-any)).

This means that the `flex-grow` property can be omitted by writing something like this:

```
flex: auto
```

or

```
flex: 250px
```

or

```
flex: 33%
```

All of the above specify the `flex-basis` component.

The (omitted) `flex-shrink` defaults to 1, as defined in the spec.

The (omitted) `flex-grow` defaults to 1, as defined in the spec.

*Just FYI, the question mark (`?`) in the value syntax means that the preceding property is optional. This means that when the browser sees something like this: `flex: 2 15em`, the unitless number is applied to `flex-grow`, because `flex-shrink` is optional, and defaults to 1 ([source](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#mult-opt)).*

Answer (score 0):

By simply writing **[`flex: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**. This is the shorthand for writing:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

So **[`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)** is set to `1` by default.

If you manually specify something like:

```
flex: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

Then **[`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)** will be `0`, and `flex-grow` will still be `1`.

Also, note that you'll need `display: flex` on the parent in order to use `flex` to being with!

Hope this helps! :)